# Class for iOS like Android.Database.Cursor

Tags: iphone, ios, database, cursor

Can anyone tell me is there any Class in iOS development like `android.database.cursor` in android development. **I am android app developer and recently started iOS development.**
I have tried Googling but couldn't get any decent solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sqlite3 framework

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app